# Ruby regular expressions for recursive grammar definitions?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I use regular expressions to validate a recursive grammar definition?  For example, say I have the following grammar:

```
   alpha := <beta> gamma | <alpha> <beta>
   beta  := delta epsilon
```

This is just an example of what I mean by recursive definition - I'm not looking for a regular expression that specifically addresses this problem, but more how to approach problems like these with regular expressions.

Comment: Your grammar seems to produce only infinite words :-)

Comment: Regular Expressions produce only regular languages, not arbitrarily recursive ones - it might not be possible. Check http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html for flavours that support recursion.

Comment: @Bergi I think I fixed it now, but double check (I'm not very good at coming up with these on the spot).

Comment: Well, that language *is* regular `delta epsilon gamma (delta epsilon)*` ([Arden's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden's_Rule) :-) Maybe check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar (or even context-sensitive?) for examples

Comment: @Kvass What Bergi is telling in the first comment is wrong. You should not care about it. Most modern regular expression engines (including Onigmo, adopted in Ruby) are much more powerful than regular grammar. Ruby's regular expression can handle recursion since Ruby 1.9.

Comment: @sawa: You're wrong. Regular Expressions can only recognize Regular Languages. That's the very *definition* of "Regular Expression". If it can recognize something that is not a Regular Language, then it's not a Regular Expression. Period. Those things that look syntactically similar to Regular Expressions but are more powerful are sometimes called "regex" or "regexp", but they are *not* Regular Expressions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That **was** the definition of regular expression at the time it was first invented. Now, it is not. The name only has historical significance. Regex or regexp are short and informal ways of saying regular expressions, and there is no difference to the meaning of these words. I have never heard of anyone distinguishing them.

Comment: @JörgWMittag For example, [RDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html) says "A `Regexp` holds a regular expression, ...". Here, by the word "regular expression", they are referring to the construct used in Onigmo regex engine. According to what you wrote, this documentation would have to be wrong. Is that what you think?

Comment: @sawa: Yep. The Perl community has got it right: they (more precisely: Larry Wall) have banned the use of the term "regular expression" for anything which is not actually a regular expression, and encourage the use of the term "regex" (plural: "regexen") instead. But calling something a "regular expression" which is not, in fact, a regular expression is confusing and an abuse of terminology and leads exactly to the kind of confusion you see here in this thread.

Comment: @JörgWMittag According to what you just wrote, the distinction between regular expression and regex/regexen is just an invention within the Perl community, and does not hold outside of that community (Larry Wall and perhaps a few followers). People do not usually distinguish them, and because of that, I don't think that distinction would help avoid confusion. It is just adding another level of confusion. If they wanted to correct the usage, they should have introduced a completely different word than just "regex". Anyway, in the context of Ruby, regular expression and regex are the same.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Furthermore, Bergi's claim was that it might not be possible to do recursion because it is a regular expression. But it is clear that what the OP meant by regular expression is what you (Perlers) call regex, since there is no such thing in Ruby as what you (Perlers) call regular expression. And that has the ability to handle recursion, so my point against Bergi's claim is correct, whether or not we adopt Perlish terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to match a recursive pattern in Ruby 1.9, in this case an arbitrary level of nested braces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

text = "... { a { b { c } b } a { d } a } ...";
match = text.match(/(?<entire>\{(?:[^{}]+|\g<entire>)*\})/).captures
puts match
```

which will print:

```
{ a { b { c } b } a { d } a }
```

A quick break down of the pattern:

```
(?<entire>        # start named capture group called <entire>
  \{              #   match the literal '{'
  (?:             #   start non capture group 1
    [^{}]+        #     match one or more chars other than '{' and '}'
    |             #     OR
    \g<entire>    #     recursively match named group <entire>
  )*              #   end non capture group 1 and repeat it zero or more times
  \}              #   match the literal '}'
)                 # end named capture group called <entire>
```